# Gulp did you forget to signal async completion

Tags: javascript, gulp

I keep getting `Did you forget to signal async completion?` when running `gulp` on my project. I updated my code to work for Gulp 4 but I am still getting an error.

```
function done() {
    console.log("Finished");
}

gulp.task('default', gulp.series(gulp.parallel(['message', 'copyHtml', 'imageMin', 'scripts'])), function() {
    done();
});
```

Comment: Since you're running 4 tasks parallel, it sounds like 1 or more of those tasks is the source of the issue, not the callback to your default task. There're many ways to [signal a task completion](https://gulpjs.com/docs/en/getting-started/async-completion), a common one I see is forgetting to return gulp.src(...). FWIW, running a custom function called `done` in the task is not a way to signal completion. Perhaps you were thinking of `cb` function mentioned in the above docs?

Answer (score 2):

Normally gulp mentions which task did not complete, but I'm guessing it's your `done` function. Update it as follows:

```js
function done(cb) {
    console.log("Finished");
    cb();
}
```

You'll also need to change the way the function is invoked:

```js
gulp.task('default', gulp.series(gulp.parallel('message', 'copyHtml', 'imageMin', 'scripts'), done));
```

Comment: what is `cb` here?

Comment: `cb` is a callback parameter that gulp will pass to the `done` function. Since the `done` function doesn't return anything, we invoke the callback to signal completion.

Comment: Okay thanks a lot, I am using gulp from a long time but don't know much about complex scripting in Gulp.